# Prevent email ending in spam-folders

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, spam, dovecot

I have been using this [dockerized mailserver](https://github.com/hardware/mailserver) to set up a mailserver and webmail for my company.

I have followed all official instructions in order to avoid emails ending in spam-folders:

- SpamAssassin validates my emails
- SPF (my server xx.xx.xx is authorized to use the mail-address)
- DKIM signature is valid
- Message parsed DMARC test
- Reverse proxy is working

Mails from my server scores a solid 10/10 on [mail-tester.com](http://www.mail-tester.com)

**Problem:** Emails send by my server ends up in spam-folders, tested on Yahoo and Hotmail (works on gmail).

My [mxtoolbox.com](http://mxtoolbox.com) test looks like this:

[image: MX test]

**Question:** What can I do to avoid ending up in spam-folders?

*Please note:* Even though similar questions has been asked on serverfault, I have not found a solution to this problem.

Comment: There is nothing more we can add to what has already been said about the topic.